# MYSQL: country with most new users in January?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, users and events:

```
**Users:**
usersid
age
geo_country
gender

**events:**
ts
usersid
event
videoid
```

Where ts is the timestamp field. And possible events are 'start_video', 'browse_catalog', 'exit_video'

I want to find out which country had the most new users in January.

My code is as follows:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT (u.geo_country), COUNT(e.userid) As Users_Ids
    FROM (SELECT userid, DATE(MIN(ts)) AS first_time
          FROM events
          WHERE ts BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-01-31 24:00:00' 
          GROUP BY userid) AS e
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userid= e.userid
    GROUP BY first_time
    ORDER BY COUNT(e.userid) DESC;
```

Since I don't have the session field, is my subquery all right in providing new users for January 2017?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Claudia

Comment: Not exactly. Query like now will select all users what have any event in Jan. You need select `min(ts)` without `between` to select first login for all users (or `min(ts) as first_time where ts < '2017-01-31 24:00:00'` ) . And only then check that `first_time between ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query that you posted is slightly incorrect.

Theoretically, the **GROUP BY** should describe how to group the data set for the aggregate function. In your primary query, you want to count the **number of users by country**, so instead of grouped by first_time, the aggregation **COUNT** should go with **GROUP BY u.geo_country**, also, as a result, the **DISTINCT** on geo_country is no longer necessary.

The **GROUP BY first_time** will also providing wrong answers as it provides the count aggregation for number of users per unique first_time recorded not by unique country.

The correct query should be:

```
SELECT u.geo_country, 
       COUNT(e.userid) As Users_Ids
FROM (SELECT userid, DATE(MIN(ts)) AS first_time
      FROM events 
      GROUP BY userid
      HAVING first_time BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-01-31 24:00:00') 
AS e
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userid= e.userid
GROUP BY u.geo_country
ORDER BY Users_Ids DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint Thai!

Comment: Just have a quick question: Why you order by Users_Ids if the question asks, countries with the most new users?

Comment: Users_Ids is the alias name for the aggregation function results, sorting by it is the same as the sorting by COUNT you use. Also the Order By clause, is a clause that run after the query is planned and the data sets retrieved, and it will not affect the result of the query.

Comment: Thank to Shiphonus pointed out a logic error in the comment section (however not a correct answer), I updated the anwser. The problem is you want to make sure the first_time to be in January, so you need to get the first time event of all users first, before filter it (which is perfectly what HAVING clause should be used for). You can do some research about what is the different between HAVING and WHERE to understand more about it.

Comment: Thanks Thai! I really appreciated your input and help on it :) Claudia

Comment: Hi Claudia, more than glad to help, if you are happy with it, can you upvote / mark the answer as accepted ? Cheers.